# Null Object Reference on TextView in getView() / fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

hi there I try create a fragment class:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
public class UpdatesFragment extends Fragment {
TextView output ;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.updates_layout, null, false);
    output = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.jsonData);
    return view;
    }
}
```

but when I run my app on device, the app break.

On android studio editor:

> method invocation 'getView().findViewById(R.id.jsonData)' may produce
>   'java.lang.NullPointerException'

On device debuger:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a
>   null object reference

and here is xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".UpdatesFragment"

    android:background="#24ff93">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HackPundit Blogs"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="38dp"
        android:textColor="#230cff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/jsonData"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right way to get View is this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.updates_layout, null, false);
output = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.jsonData);
```

You have to use the inflated view to find views instead of `getView()`

Answer (score 0):

The right way to reference a view in fragment is inside this method;

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

//reference your fragments views here
    output = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.jsonData);
}
```